# raising NotAuthorized exception in application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to raise an exception from `application_controller` file for any actions other than `read`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_action :authenticate_request
  attr_reader :current_user
  
  private

  def authenticate_request
    @current_user = AuthorizeApiRequest.call(request.headers).result
    render json: { error: 'Not Authorized' }, status: 401 unless @current_user
  end

  def authorize!(action)
     raise NotAuthorized if action != :read && !current_user.admin?
     true
  end

end
```

But when I am making a `POST` request, the exception itself is throwing error. The following is the error.

```
NameError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController::NotAuthorized):
```

How can I fix this without having to add any new modules?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not do a `render json: { error: 'Not Authorized' }, status: 401 if action != :read && !current_user&.admin?` ? Any reason it has to be an exception?

Comment: what is NotAuthorized and where it is defined?

Answer (score 0):

In rails there is no in-built exception called `NotAuthorized`, so when you try to `raise` this, rails doesn't know what to do. You can do this in two ways:

1. You can raise directly using built-in exceptions or create your own. Ex:

   ```rb
   raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not authorized')
   # or
   raise ActionController::BadRequest.new('Not authorized')
   # or
   raise ActionController::MethodNotAllowed.new('Not authorized')
   ```
2. I recommend creating an external module and including it here, it keeps you code clean.